# Wordpress Boilerplate - Ajax with plugin

Tags: php, ajax, plugins, wordpress

I'm working on to writing a Wordpress Plugin based on: http://wppb.io/

My issue is: I'm working on Public view and try to use Ajax to connect with backend.I'm use: public/js/ xxx-public.js to place all ajax function handle and Define some hooks:

```
    wp_enqueue_script( $this->plugin_name, plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/xxx-public.js', array( 'jquery' ), $this->version, false );

    wp_register_script( 'district_handle', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/xxx-public.js', array( 'jquery' ), $this->version, false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'district_handle');

    wp_register_script( 'ret_cus_handle', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/xxx-public.js' , array( 'jquery' ), $this->version, false);
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ret_cus_handle');

    wp_register_script( 'order_ret_cus_handle', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/xxx-public.js', array( 'jquery' ), $this->version, false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'order_ret_cus_handle');
```

It works.

But problem is: the website will generate 4 xxx-public.js in header. I only want one.

I'm just a newbie with WP plugin. I hope to get your solution. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use wordpress function wp_script_is() to determine if a script is enqueued already and use it in a conditional code like this below.

Make a function for scripts you want to enqueue first like this.

```
function custom-script( ) {
    wp_enqueue_script('xxx-public.js'); 
}
```

Then write a conditional code.

```
if ( ! wp_script_is( 'custom-script', 'enqueued' ) ) {
    // your code here
}
```

Make sure you check wp_script_is() from wordpress function references as it takes two parameters $handle and $list.

Hopes this helps for you.

Comment: Your suggestion isnt work but I found out the answer. thanks in advance